# Serializing java.io.Serializable instance into JSON with Spring and Jackson JSON

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, jackson

I am getting an instance of `Serializable` out of some internal APIs. The `Serializable` instance is actually `Long` or `String`, etc. Is there a way to make a DTO that can handle this situation? Using `private Serializable value;` the JSON ends up with `value: {}`.

**UPDATE**

Here is a reduced example of the code in question:

```
@Controller
public class SomeController
{
  //...
  public MyDto getInfo(Long id)
  {
    MyDto result = new MyDto();
    Serializable obj = svc.getInfo(id);
    // obj is either Long, or String, or one of few more fundamental Java types
    result.setValue(obj);
    return result;
  }
}

public class MyDto
{
  private Serializable value;
  public void setValue(Serializable info)
  {
    this.value = value;
  }
  public Serializable getValue()
  {
    return value;
  }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

I have found the answer to my problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20494813/341065

Comment: You could maybe do it with a custom `JsonDeserializer`.

Answer (score 9):

Note that Jackson does not use `java.io.Serializable` for anything: there is no real value for adding that. It gets ignored.

Given this, Jackson will see values as equivalent of whatever actual type is (for serialization, i.e. writing JSON); or, when reading, as equivalent of `java.lang.Object`.

If you know the actual type, you could annotate property with `@JsonDeserialize(as=ActualType.class)` to give a hint. But if actual values are `String`s and `Long`s, this really should not be needed.

Comment: The actual type is one of few Java types like `Long` or `String`. The internal API returns `Serializable`. I have tried passing just `private Object value;` in the DTO but I get nothing in the JSON.

Comment: Jackson definitely should serialize Long as basic JSON number, String as JSON String. But do you return these values as-is, or in a wrapper Object of some kind?