# How to use Spring context from integration tests

Tags: spring, javabeans, applicationcontext

I have an spring application deployed on tomcat.

I want to run my integration tests and not to use webservices. I want to use beans instead.

I understand that it is a bit strange, usually WS's should be used for this purposes, however Question - **how can I access to spring context in order to get beans from it?**

Can you advise me some direction where to look?

Answer (score 0):

You can call `getBean` method on your spring context, e.g. `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext` object (or XML, which implements `BeanFactory`)

If `getContext()` return you the spring context, get bean:

```
 (MyBeanObject) getContext().getBean("myBeanName")
```

Comment: but how can I access it remotely? 
I have my IT's on my local machine, and the application with its context is deployed on some env

Comment: using serialization, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38457074/spring-mvc-should-my-domain-classes-implement-serializable-for-over-the-wire-t